# runtime error trying to resize storage that is not resizable

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, data-augmentation, pytorch-dataloader

I am working on a script with data augmentation techniques centercropping,cornercropping and horizontalflip
and I want to keep only the centercropping an horizontalflip
this is the functions
the first one is for the training data

```
     def get_train_utils(opt, model_parameters):
    assert opt.train_crop in ['random', 'corner', 'center']
    spatial_transform = []
    #if opt.train_crop == 'random':
       # spatial_transform.append(
           # RandomResizedCrop(
               # opt.sample_size, (opt.train_crop_min_scale, 1.0),
                #(opt.train_crop_min_ratio, 1.0 / opt.train_crop_min_ratio)))
    #elif opt.train_crop == 'corner':
       # scales = [1.0]
       # scale_step = 1 / (2**(1 / 4))
        #for _ in range(1, 5):
           # scales.append(scales[-1] * scale_step)
        #spatial_transform.append(MultiScaleCornerCrop(opt.sample_size, scales))
    if opt.train_crop == 'center':
        spatial_transform.append(Resize(opt.sample_size))
        spatial_transform.append(CenterCrop(opt.sample_size))
    normalize = get_normalize_method(opt.mean, opt.std, opt.no_mean_norm,
                                     opt.no_std_norm)
    if not opt.no_hflip:
        spatial_transform.append(RandomHorizontalFlip())
    if opt.colorjitter:
        spatial_transform.append(ColorJitter())
    spatial_transform.append(ToTensor())
    if opt.input_type == 'flow':
        spatial_transform.append(PickFirstChannels(n=2))
    spatial_transform.append(ScaleValue(opt.value_scale))
    spatial_transform.append(normalize)
    spatial_transform = Compose(spatial_transform)

    assert opt.train_t_crop in ['random', 'center']
    temporal_transform = []
    if opt.sample_t_stride > 1:
        temporal_transform.append(TemporalSubsampling(opt.sample_t_stride))
   # if opt.train_t_crop == 'random':
       # temporal_transform.append(TemporalRandomCrop(opt.sample_duration))
    if opt.train_t_crop == 'center':
        temporal_transform.append(TemporalCenterCrop(opt.sample_duration))
    temporal_transform = TemporalCompose(temporal_transform)

    train_data = get_training_data(opt.video_path, opt.annotation_path,
                                   opt.dataset, opt.input_type, opt.file_type,
                                   spatial_transform, temporal_transform)
    if opt.distributed:
        train_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
            train_data)
    else:
        train_sampler = None
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data,
                                               batch_size=opt.batch_size,
                                               shuffle=(train_sampler is None),
                                               num_workers=opt.n_threads,
                                               pin_memory=True,
                                               sampler=train_sampler,
                                               worker_init_fn=worker_init_fn)
```

the second one is for validation data

```
     def get_val_utils(opt):
    normalize = get_normalize_method(opt.mean, opt.std, opt.no_mean_norm,
                                     opt.no_std_norm)
    spatial_transform = [
        Resize(opt.sample_size),
        CenterCrop(opt.sample_size),
        ToTensor()
    ]
    if opt.input_type == 'flow':
        spatial_transform.append(PickFirstChannels(n=2))
    spatial_transform.extend([ScaleValue(opt.value_scale), normalize])
    spatial_transform = Compose(spatial_transform)

    temporal_transform = []
    if opt.sample_t_stride > 1:
        temporal_transform.append(TemporalSubsampling(opt.sample_t_stride))
    temporal_transform.append(
        TemporalEvenCrop(opt.sample_duration, opt.n_val_samples))
    temporal_transform = TemporalCompose(temporal_transform)

    val_data, collate_fn = get_validation_data(opt.video_path,
                                               opt.annotation_path, opt.dataset,
                                               opt.input_type, opt.file_type,
                                               spatial_transform,
                                               temporal_transform)
    if opt.distributed:
        val_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
            val_data, shuffle=False)
    else:
        val_sampler = None
    val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_data,
                                             batch_size=(opt.batch_size //
                                                         opt.n_val_samples),
                                             shuffle=False,
                                             num_workers=opt.n_threads,
                                             pin_memory=True,
                                             sampler=val_sampler,
                                             worker_init_fn=worker_init_fn,
                                             collate_fn=collate_fn)
```

and the last one is for inference data

```
    def get_inference_utils(opt):
    assert opt.inference_crop in ['center', 'nocrop']

    normalize = get_normalize_method(opt.mean, opt.std, opt.no_mean_norm,
                                     opt.no_std_norm)

    spatial_transform = [Resize(opt.sample_size)]
    if opt.inference_crop == 'center':
        spatial_transform.append(CenterCrop(opt.sample_size))
    spatial_transform.append(ToTensor())
    if opt.input_type == 'flow':
        spatial_transform.append(PickFirstChannels(n=2))
    spatial_transform.extend([ScaleValue(opt.value_scale), normalize])
    spatial_transform = Compose(spatial_transform)

    temporal_transform = []
    if opt.sample_t_stride > 1:
        temporal_transform.append(TemporalSubsampling(opt.sample_t_stride))
    temporal_transform.append(
        SlidingWindow(opt.sample_duration, opt.inference_stride))
    temporal_transform = TemporalCompose(temporal_transform)

    inference_data, collate_fn = get_inference_data(
        opt.video_path, opt.annotation_path, opt.dataset, opt.input_type,
        opt.file_type, opt.inference_subset, spatial_transform,
        temporal_transform)

    inference_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        inference_data,
        batch_size=opt.inference_batch_size,
        shuffle=False,
        num_workers=opt.n_threads,
        pin_memory=True,
        worker_init_fn=worker_init_fn,
        collate_fn=collate_fn)

    return inference_loader, inference_data.class_names
```

the functions used are imported from :

```
    from spatial_transforms import (Compose, Normalize, Resize, CenterCrop,
                                CornerCrop, MultiScaleCornerCrop,
                                RandomResizedCrop, RandomHorizontalFlip,
                                ToTensor, ScaleValue, ColorJitter,
                                PickFirstChannels)
    from temporal_transforms import (LoopPadding, TemporalRandomCrop,
                                 TemporalCenterCrop, TemporalEvenCrop,
                                 SlidingWindow, TemporalSubsampling)
    from temporal_transforms import Compose as TemporalCompose
```

I just removed th random an corner cropping from the get_train_util function
the line with the # symbole and kept only the center cropping
but got this error

> runtime error trying to resize storage that is not resizable

the traceback
[traceback_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZsiA.png)
the complete code is in this github repository [link_to_completecode](https://github.com/kenshohara/3D-ResNets-PyTorch)
I think it's related to the dataloader , it'not able to load the data after I tried to modified it
any suggestions what should I do?

Comment: complete traceback required. [mre]

Comment: I juste added a screenshot of the complete traceback